# Anglicize for Japanese

Tags: terminology, transliteration

English speakers will change pronunciation and spelling of foreign words to make them easier to manage and we call this Anglicization. Japanese do this too, adding extra vowels to foreign words to make them roll off the Japanese tongue more easily. Is there a word for this, like "Japanization"? All I can find is "transliteration into Japanese", but that is awkward and sounds too mechanical.

Comment: _Japanese loan word phonology_ is what I'd call it in English. Google on that to see lots of information.

Comment: Transliteration is really the correct word to use.

Answer (score 4):

OED has

> **Nipponize** *verb*
>
> *trans.* To make Japanese in character.
>
> 1942   H. Mears *Year of Wild Boar* 82   We saw a modan-style movie-theater where the picture featured Harold Lloyd; but he was talking in Japanese, for they had Nipponized the sound track.

That's not quite the same as Anglicize and Anglicization, but *Nipponization* may suffice if you are using it in a similar context. OED mentions it can be spelled with or without an initial capital.

[*Nippon* is the Japanese name for Japan. Apparently *Japan* comes via Chinese.]

Comment: _Nipponize_ may be in the dictionary, but that doesn't mean that people will necessarily have heard it.

Comment: Note that the definition involves *Japanese in character* and thus refers to say adapting Shakespeare not pronouncing names from Shakespeare in Japanese.

Answer (score 1):

Urban dictionary gives [katakanize](http://ja.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=katakanize):

> To transcribe an English word into the Japanese katakana alphabet by
>   splitting it apart into intonational syllables.
>
> *Would you katakanize 'Larry' as 'Rarii?'*

Comment: That only fits some instances of this phenomenon, though. I doubt you’d find many people who consider _Tōkyō_ a katakanisation, though it is without a doubt a Japanisation.